# How to create a Numpy Index with colons everywhere except at one variable coordinate?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I would like to create an index in the form of

```
[:, :, :, 0, :, :, :, :]
```

where the position of `0` is determined by a variable, say `axis` to slice a NumPy array.   Obviously there are two special cases that are easy to treat:

- `axis = 0` would be equivalent to `[0, ...]`
- `axis = -1` would be equivalent to `[..., 0]`

But I wonder how this can be done for any `axis` value?

Comment: Would [`nump.take()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) accomplish what you're trying to do?

Comment: Indeed! Thanks! I was not aware of that routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a tuple and use `slice(None)` in place of `:`:

```
def custom_index(arr, position, index):
    idx = [slice(None)] * len(arr.shape)
    idx[position] = index
    return arr[tuple(idx)]
```

Quick test:

```
mat = np.random.random((5, 3))
assert np.all(mat[2, :] == custom_index(mat, 0, 2))  # mat[(2, slice(None))]
assert np.all(mat[:, 2] == custom_index(mat, 1, 2))  # mat[(slice(None), 2))]
```

**EDIT:** as pointed out in the comment, the proper way is  [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)

Comment: The proper way is np.take as suggested above.  But that would only work if one were to slice the array as a rvalue (i.e. to read from an array).  If I want to use the slice for 'writing' to the array I should use your `custom_index`?  Or perhaps there is a NumPy function for that purpose too?

Comment: @kMaster I do not know if there is a numpy function for that, but you can use this method for assignment, `arr[tuple(idx)]=x` works